# Is it possible I write a (Windows or Linux) service by QtService?

Tags: c++, windows, linux, qt, service

Is it possible I write a (Windows or Linux) service by QtService ?
I think QtService is only for connecting to a service , not for writing it. yes ?
if you have an example, please give me.

Comment: QtService is for writing services.

Comment: http://doc.trolltech.com/solutions/qtservice/qtservice.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is the exact intention of [QtService](https://github.com/qtproject/qt-solutions/tree/master/qtservice). Please see the [example http server](https://github.com/qtproject/qt-solutions/tree/master/qtservice/examples).